# Get highest count for specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to return highest count of keywords which belongs to specific kategorie, subkategorie and type.

We have to use `WHERE SubKat_ID IS NOT NULL and only WHERE Type = A`

So something like this:

> SELECT 'get highest count of keywords' from table WHERE Kat_ID = x And
>   Type = 'A' And SubKat IS NOT NULL

Example data:

```
ID  Keyword_ID  Kat_ID   SubKat_ID    Type
29  1            247       NULL        A
30  2            247       NULL        A
31  3            247       NULL        A
32  3            247       96          A
33  4            247       96          A
34  2            247       96          A
35  3            247       95          A
37  4            33        NULL        B
40  6            33        44          A
41  3            33        44          A
42  4            33        66          A
43  11           33        66          A
44  7            33        66          A
45  2            33        66          A
46  8            55        NULL        A
```

**Couple examples based on data at the bottom of my post:**

**1st Test:**

```
WHERE Kat_ID = 247 And Type = 'A'
```

it should says: 3 because we have: 3x rows for 96 and 1x95

**2nd Test:**

```
WHERE Kat_ID = 33 And Type = 'A'
```

it should says: 4 because we have: 2x rows for 44 and 4x66

**3rd Test:**

```
WHERE Kat_ID = 55 And Type = 'A'
```

it should says: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should deal with your edge case too:

```
select coalesce(max(t.cnt), 0) as max_cnt
  from (select count(*) as cnt
          from tbl
         where kat_id = x
           and type = 'A'
           and SubKat_ID is not null
         group by SubKat_ID) t
```

Comment: thanks that what i was looking for - by the way why you used coalesce whats that for?

Comment: For your last case, because there are no rows that satisfy your condition, the `max()` function call returns `null`.  The call to `coalesce` is saying that if `max(t.cnt)` is null, replace that with `0`.

Comment: Just to add to @sstan excellent post. `COALESCE` is being used as an `ISNULL` equivalent in the above. But there can sometimes be behaviour differences so it's worth checking the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190349(v=sql.105).aspx). Also worth pointing out that `ISNULL` is not ANSI Standard whereas `COALESCE` is. Here is a good link to more indepth behaviour and performance differences [MSSQLtips - Coalesce v IsNull](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*)
FROM T
WHERE Kat_ID = 247 And Type = 'A' 
GROUP BY SubKat_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: i added to your query WHERE SubKat IS NOT NULL but i am not getting 0 e.g for my 3rd test.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(1) as [Count], Kat_ID, SubKat_ID, [Type]

from table 

WHERE Kat_ID = x And Type = 'A' And SubKat IS NOT NULL

group by Kat_ID, SubKat_ID, [Type]
```

You want to use the group by clause to tell the engine to *group* equal values in these column together.

Comment: it is returning me rows instead of number

Comment: Select statements return rows. Sometimes one row with one column in it, but it is always rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1  CASE WHEN RecType = 'NULL' THEN 0 ELSE cnt END AS RecordCount FROM--TOP 1 FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, 'NOT NULL' as RecType
    FROM #tmp
    WHERE Kat_ID = 33 AND Type = 'A' 
        AND SubKat_ID is not null
    GROUP BY SubKat_ID
UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, 'NULL' AS RecType 
    FROM #tmp WHERE Kat_ID = 33 AND Type = 'A' 
        AND SubKat_ID IS NULL
) AS T1
ORDER BY cnt desc
```

But I feel I'm missing a simpler way.

Comment: ok but like in my 3rd example where kat 55 i should get 0 but i see there is nothing how to change that to get 0 instead?

Comment: So you want to still get a count in the event that the only records that exist have NULL for SubKat_ID?

Comment: exactly thats true

Answer (score 0):

```
select  max(count(1)) from stck
WHERE Kat_ID = 247 And Type = 'A' and SubKat_ID  is not null
group by SubKat_ID 

select  max(count(1)) from stck
WHERE Kat_ID = 33 And Type = 'A' and SubKat_ID  is not null
group by SubKat_ID 

select  nvl(max(count(1)),0)  from stck
WHERE Kat_ID = 55 And Type = 'A' and SubKat_ID  is not null
group by SubKat_ID 

Have written above queries on top oracle db
```

Comment: These are not valid queries, even in Oracle.  You can't have double aggregate function calls like that: `max(count(1))`.

Comment: I just executed and saw the results, verified and then posted :)

Comment: Nice, I didn't know Oracle allowed that with `group by` clauses. Too bad the question is for SQL Server, which doesn't support that :(